Jet bundle question
Let $E \to M$ be a holomorphic vector bundle.
Is there a metric on the first jet bundle $J^1 E$ that can be defined in terms of metrics on $E$ and $M$?

This is not exactly my area, but I am pretty sure that there is such a metric. For the first jet bundle, you have the jet exact sequence
$$
0\to T^*M\otimes E\to J^1E\to E\to 0.
$$
Assuming that $E$ is hermitian and has a holomorphic structure, the Chern connection is a canonical connection $E$. A connection on $E$ is equivalent to a splitting of the jet exact sequence (with the split $J^1E\to T^*M\otimes E$ induced by the covariant derivative). Hence under your assumptions, you get a canonical isomorphism $J^1E\cong (T^*M\otimes E)\oplus E$ and on the latter bundle, you have a hermitian metric induced by the hermitian metrics on $E$ and $TM$.

Thanks. Sounds natural enough. I was not aware of this formalism.

Doesn't your sequence define the Atiyah class, which in general is an obstruction to the existence of a holomorphic connection? In other words, the Chern connection is not holomorphic, so it cannot give you a holomorphic splitting $J^1E = E \oplus (T^*M \otimes E)$. (Though I have only learned about the Atiyah class a few days ago, so my understanding might be incomplete).

As far as I understand the question, there is no need for the splitting to be holomorphic, since this is not needed to get a hermitian metric on $J^1E$.
